# How to solve MNP (minimum norm) problem in SVM?

Tags: svm, lagrange-multipliers, duality

I'm reading an article, which says that **MNP** (minimum norm problem) can be solved as **SVM**.
In the minimum norm problem, we're given a set of points in $R^d$ and need to find a point in **convex hull** of our points closest to the origin.

In SVM method we're minimizing the lagrangian 
$$\mathcal{L}(w, b, \alpha) = \dfrac{1}{2}||w||^2 + \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i [y_i(w^Tx - b) - 1].$$
i.e.in dual-form maximizing the function $W(\alpha):$
$$\max_\alpha W(\alpha) =  \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i - \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i, j = 1}^m y^{(i)}y^{(j)}\alpha^{(i)}\alpha^{(j)}<x^{(i)}, x^{(j)}>.$$

**1)** How we can apply it for MNP-problem? 
Probably, **0** (origin) would stand for one support vector and the closest-point from the convex hull is for another.

**2)** But how will it look like a dual-form of the problem?

**3)** Will be $y_i$ labels $y_i = 1$ for any point of convex hull and $y_i = -1$ for origin?

**4)** And how can i find(if i can) $\alpha_i$ (Lagrange multipliers)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if you perform a crisp linear SVM classifier between two groups, one of it being your data and the other being the null vector, either the algorithm will fail because **0** is in the convex hull of those points (groups not linearly separable), or a solution will be found, where one of the SVs will clearly be **0**, and the other *k* vectors define the [*k*-face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_(geometry)#k-face) of the hull nearest to the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [this article](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~idsp/Signal%20and%20Image%20Processing%20Files/papers/mavroforakis/SVM-Geom-IEEE_rev1c.pdf):

> the solution of the linearly separable
>   classification problem is equivalent to finding the points of the
>   two convex hulls [21] (each generated by the training patterns
>   of each class) which are closest to each other and the
>   maximum margin hyperplane a) bisects and b) is normal to the
>   line segment joining these two closest points

So yes, you should classifying your points as belonging to one-class, and the other class should just be the origin. You should have some support vectors, as well as the classifying norm. If there's a single support vector then it is the closest point. Otherwise, you can just take the $w$ vector and see where it intersects the tangential $w'$ that goes through the support vectors (assuming separability). For non-separable case, one could still follow a similar approach, however one would have to check the intersection for each support vector separately in order to find the point closest to the origin.